# JS: Redirecting with 'window.location' not saving history in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect

I'm trying to redirect without losing the history in Firefox.
I have used the next without success:

```
window.location = "http://example.com";
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
window.location.assign("http://example.com");
```

Also tried using 'document' instead of 'window'.

I get redirected, but the history is not added (or deleted) from the browser

Any ideas!?

Note: I'm not calling this function directly, I'm calling it after a succesfull jQuery Ajax request to the server:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  ...
  success: function (data) {},
});
```

the variable data contains the JS redirect function (`window.location.href = "http://example.com"`)

Comment: The chosen answer, while surely good advice, doesn't solve the problem posed in this question.  This one does, however http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864633/assigning-to-document-location-href-without-clobbering-history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check out this article on URL Design: http://warpspire.com/posts/url-design/ In particular the section titled "Everything should have a url". Basically you will want to use the history.pushState function to add the new url to the browser history. You can check out similar stackoverflow post as well: [Update URL on AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134280/jquery-update-url-on-ajax-call) or [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/how-do-i-with-javascript-change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new/4222584#4222584)

Comment: The link is broken, the new link can be found here https://warpspire.com/posts/url-design

Answer (score -1):

If you redirect within 15 seconds then Firefox won't save the previous page in history, because otherwise clicking back would display the previous page for no more than 15 seconds before it would redirect again, thereby serving only to annoy the user.

Comment: That is in case I automatically redirect on page load, but is not the case. I redirect only on a specific user action that calls a function.

Comment: Got some documentation to back this up?

Comment: Maybe this was true in 2011 but it doesn't seem to be causing the issue today, which still seems to exist in Firefox...

Comment: @JoshHarrison I don't have easy access to what the Firefox code looked like in 2011, but as far as I can tell the current code saves the previous page unless the redirect happens during page load or by a meta refresh with a timeout of no more than 15 seconds.

Comment: @Neil interesting, thank you for looking at that. Some other factor must be causing my Firefox history issue…