# Adding / updating a paramenter in URL with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 16 database results shown on my website. Using a load more button, the user can load the next 16 database items and they get appended into the container.

Im trying to make a way so that if the user clicks back after visiting a link, they will get shown the same amount of results as they had loaded.

My plan for this is to add a page number to the url after each load more function. When the user clicks back in the browser, i can then use that parameter in the LIMIT php claus.

So, in my ajax response, i append the data and then i wish to add a page number to the url, or update the page number if there already is one.

An example of what i want to achieve is:

www.mydomain.com/?page=1

I have made a jsfiddle with a basic button click function just for testing since im away from my laptop until later.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BtL2/)

And the code just incase:

```
var url = document.URL;
var pageID = '1';
$("#addtourl").click(function(){
    // add page id to the url
    alert(url);
});
```

Where the url is alerted i want to modify the URL. I already create a page ID so thats not an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi!what did u try till now ?  code ?

Comment: Just added what i missed :) Havent tried anything yet as the idea just came into my head and not sure on modifying the URL without redirection.

Comment: Hello :) This is not possible  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134280/update-url-on-ajax-call

Comment: use pjax instead of ajax

Comment: @PratikJoshi the very link you posted says it IS possible with HTML5 pushState. You should read it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML 5 [history.pushState](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html) function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript/4222584#4222584) .