# how to Handle new window,Pop ups and redirect to _self?

Tags: javascript

I am working on Application which should redirect any new window or pop ups in same current window.
ie go to http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm and press "New window" button a new window pops up,I do not want this to happen ie new window should not be opened,It should open in same window i click the element.

So in total irrespective of any JavaScript written in n site i want the pop ups and new window redirect to _self

Can anyone give me a java script which will do this?

Comment: Not likely. You want to override any target set by any external website? Good luck with that :) - If you know the name of the window it is targetting, you could set your own window name when loading the external site. Any other idea would likely involve running through a proxy...

Comment: yes targeting external websites :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect your current site using window.location

```
window.location="http://www.w3schools.com"
```

This wont behave as a pop up, but will send your page to location you provide.
If you want a pop up behaviour then, use the script as mentioned in your link and close the current window using `window.close();` , which I guess will serve your purpose.

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/how-do-i-with-javascript-change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new) might help you.