# Proxy application and redirection to new https url hiding this url

Tags: java, web, https, jboss, redirect

I'm new in web programming, so sorry if I'm asking trivial questions.

We have web application with login page using https, web server is JBoss, implementation in java/javascript. Lets assume, that we get this page accessing www.aaa.com, lets call this login page A.

The goal is to write proxy application with similar login page + some additional info (lets call it B) that will be accessed by www.bbb.com. Proxy application should read credentials, do some job and redirect request to www.aaa.com with those credentials, after that aaa.com will perform its job. In case of login failure, B page (that is part of bbb.com) should display the same error as was supposed to display page A.
During redirection, I can't change URL from bbb.com to aaa.com. It should always show bbb.com although we are doing job on another web server.

Please advise how it can be done (links to examples of redirection implementation are appreciated), whether there are some pitfalls related to redirection to https and hiding target url, what should be performed in aaa.com to allow such access.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [HTML frame](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frames.htm)

see [HTML frame tag URL of browser not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214717/html-frame-tag-url-of-browser-not-changing)