# just add url on only address bar of browser

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

i want just add url in address bar of browser `Note: dont want redirect`

e.i i have a url `www.example.com/index.html`

i want set url on 'address bar' like `www.example.com/index/page2.html`

i use `document.location.hash = 'foo';`

`but it is add only # data
like www.example.com/index.html#foo`

`note : i dont want to redirect only want to add url in address bar so don't answer document.location like that`

any solution for that ?

Comment: You can't do that, and it's for security reasons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601609/how-to-manipulate-the-url-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Please check out the links posted here. Both describe how to do it. The security concerns restrict you from setting it to another url, but you can alter the path with the history API.

Comment: @chucktator the best he could do is from his examplee is `www.example.com/index.html/page2.html`

Comment: @JaredMcAteer  Within your own domain you are allowed to change the path and filename portion of the url to anything you want. Facebook does it, Google does it and I've tried it out myself as well.

Comment: it is possible see this blog and click any post title then it is change in address bar of browser see this http://freesubmiturlindia.blogspot.in

Answer (score 2):

Have a read here.

http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate

Might help.

```
window.history.pushState('abc', "Title", "/new-url");
```

Comment: `NOTE : window.history.pushState('abc', "Title", "/new-url");` not work on IE

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done. This is a security feature to make it harder to spoof a site (e.g. for phishing attacks)

Comment: The domain can't be changed. The rest of the URL can. Thus no possibility of spoofing.

Comment: Quite right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this without using a redirect.

Here's a way to achieve your goal though.

Create page for `www.example.com/index/page2.html` that contains of a frame of `www.example.com/index.html`

In `www.example.com/index.html` redirect the user to `www.example.com/index/page2.html` if the  `www.example.com/index.html` isn't inside a frame.