# How to change the querystring on the same page without postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to change the querystring on the page where I write notes. When I save the note I want the querystring to have the entry for that note. So after the initial save the user can update based on the querystring. But to update the querystring I need to do full postback. Is there anyway to change the querystring like this?

Comment: this should help you on your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970078/modifying-a-query-string-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot change the current query string without reloading. You could use the frgament portion of the url though (`#`). Setting the fragment portion might allow you to add some entries to the browser history without reloading.

For example if your current url is `http://example.com/foo` you could change it to `http://example.com/foo#bar=baz` without reloading the current page.

Comment: Because that's the fragment separator in an url.

Comment: +1 for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096201/build-query-string-for-system-net-httpclient-get and this answer