# Storing a value in querystring but still show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### My HTML:

```
<a href="?id=2" id="showdiv">Open div and store values</a>
<div id="divtoshow" style="display:none;">Hello</div>
```

### My jQuery:

```
$("a#showdiv").click(function(){
    $("#divtoshow").show();
}
```

### My Problem:

When I click on the link it must show the div and add the query string but it doesn't work,  because if I click the link it restarts the page to add the query string and then the div won't show. But I still need it to add the query string then.

Comment: You cannot do it without post back. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632472/how-to-change-the-querystring-on-the-same-page-without-postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your anchor to

```
<a href="#showDiv?id=2" id="showdiv">Open div and store values</a>
```

In simple terms then it won't refresh the page, instead it'll bring the element with id `showdiv` to view,. of course  if it exists..

Answer (score 0):

1) Since id is unique, you can use `#showdiv` instead of `a#showdiv`

2) Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default behaviour of your click

3) You're missing `#` to target div with id `divtoshow`

```
$("#showdiv").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divtoshow").show();
});
```

Comment: But I still need it to add the query string then.

Comment: You cannot do it without reloading page.

Answer (score 0):

use `preventDefault` to prevent default action:

```
 $("#showdiv").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#divtoshow").show();
  }
```

Comment: But I still need it to add the query string then. How will it add it

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
$("a#showdiv").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();// not sure if needed.
    $("#divtoshow").show();
}
```

and it should stop the link normal behaviour.

**EDIT**
for adding the text of the div clicked:

```
$("a#showdiv").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();// not sure if needed.
    var id = $('#showdiv').attr('id').split('=')[1];// if only one parameter posible
    $("#divtoshow").show();
}
```

Comment: But I still need it to add the query string then.

Comment: I don't know if i understand, do you mean to add the text of the div clicked? if it's it then:

Answer (score 0):

Use following JQuery Code.

```
$("#showdiv").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divtoshow").show();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwwpq/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
```

and on document.ready()

```
if(getParameterByName("id") == 2)
{
    $("#divtoshow").show();
}
```