# How to change query params without changing route/action?

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

In my view I render collection and I have sort buttons.
When sort button is clicked then collection is fetched with some custom query param (like `&sort=id+desc`). It works but I would like to also change url querystring to this query param (`&sort=id+desc`). The problem is that it works but it re-renders whole view as router just redirects to different action (actually the same action but with different query params).

How I can just change url query param without reloading view and also add it to history?

I am using pushState in my app

Comment: Can you show us the router config?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying a query string without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970078/modifying-a-query-string-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: I forgot to tell I am using `pushState` -> jquery.History does not support it..

Answer (score 0):

You should use backbone router for this.

When application stars you need to run:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

To change the URL just use you router:

```
router.navigate("something?key=value");
```

If you don't have a router you just create one:

```
var router = new Backbone.Router();
```