# Without redirecting passing the querystring value to current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I want to pass the query string value without redirecting to current page I have tried these code but I can even see the query string value variable to pass in these page.I have attached my code below.help me out from these problem
             Thanks in advance

Aspx design code

```
 <div class="col span_1_of_1">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gridweeks" runat="server" CssClass="grid" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" ShowFooter="true" Style="width: 40%" AllowPaging="true" PageIndex="0" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="gridweeks_PageIndexChanging">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#dddddd" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="weekmonth" HeaderText="Available Month" SortExpression="weekmonth" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="dayweek" HeaderText="Available Weeks" SortExpression="dayweek" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit / Delete">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkeditweek" runat="server" Style="color: black" CommandName="assign1" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("dayweek")+","+Eval("weekmonth")%>' OnClick="lnkeditweek_Click1"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="color:#2389C9"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#32404E" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#32404E" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="right" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="#fff" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="batch" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [dayweek], [weekmonth] FROM [tblslots]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
```

C# code

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        lbltxt.Visible = true;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            if (btn.CommandName == "assign1")
            {
                string[] commandArgs = btn.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
                zeroval = commandArgs[0];
                firstval = commandArgs[1];


                for (int j = 0; j < gridweeks.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    GridViewRow gw = gridweeks.Rows[j];
                    //string months = gw.Cells[0].Text;
                    // string weeks = gw.Cells[1].Text;
                    for (int i = 0; i < gridsem.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        GridViewRow gs = gridsem.Rows[i];
                        string semester = gs.Cells[0].Text;
                        lbltxt.Text = "You are going to edit for Section : " + Request.QueryString["section"] + ", Week : " + zeroval + " , Session : " + Request.QueryString["session"] + " , Semester : " + semester + " , Month : " + firstval + "";
                        mp5edit.Show();
                    }
                }
                string longurl = "viewavailableweeks.aspx?&ins=" + Request.QueryString["ins"] + "&section=" + Request.QueryString["section"] + "&session=" + Request.QueryString["session"] + "&academicyear=" + Request.QueryString["academicyear"] + "&month='" + firstval + "'+&week='" + firstval + "'";
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longurl);
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
                longurl = uriBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Without redirecting to current page?? You can store the values in hidden fields or can use session variables or check the following  [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8055/Transferring-page-values-to-another-page)

Comment: Check this out:
[other stackoverflow post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970078/modifying-a-query-string-without-reloading-the-page