# Add or update query parameter using react-router v4 without re-rendering main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's say that we have a React application with an entrypoint that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Application from './Application';


ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Application />
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Somewhere deep in the React application, I'd like to add (or update) query parameters in response to some user action. I could use the `history.push()` method which react-router [provides](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md), but using that method causes `Application` to be re-rendered.

Is it possible to add or update query parameters without `Application` being re-rendered? I have found that I can change query parameters without `Application` being re-rendered if I [use the History API directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279428/4297741), but this feels like a hack.

Comment: Doesn't feel like a hack to me, feels like a viable solution. Wrapped history is there to re-render and I don't think they provide a silent option, that would be just unwrapped history imo.

Comment: I think it's a hack because doing this causes react-router's `history` and `location` objects not to be updated. Those can be useful. I'm actually running into a situation right now where it would be useful to read from them.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently reading a book about react and had the same issue.

What I found out is that you need to add **shouldComponentUpdate** method to the parent component and validate if the **location.search** value is different

`this.props.location.search !== nextProps.location.search`

Returning true from that validation will re-render the component

P.S.
The book was using React Router v3 so I was having a hard time with the whole app being updated and the nested routes

P.P.S.
I'm using history which now is a package outside of React Router

Comment: In this example, `Application` does not have any props. But your broader point is correct: I could implement `shouldComponentUpdate` or make `Application` a `PureComponent`, which would prevent it from re-rendering until any props have changed. That might actually be a cleaner workaround than using the history API and I appreciate the suggestion. Still, I wonder if react-router has a way to change query params without re-rendering everything, in the same way the history API has a way to change query params without reloading.