# How to check a function before execute another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that i have an function like this :

```
function toggleLayers(layers,id)
    {
        var i, l = layers.length;
        if ($('#'+id).is(':checked')) {
            for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
                layers[i].setMap(map);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
                layers[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

With this feature I check whether it is a checked checkbox or not. The problem is with another function:

```
function refreshpage(){
        var sdat = document.getElementById('refreshi').value ;      
        var enddate13 = sdat.replace('.','');       
        var enddate1 = enddate13.replace('.','');       
        var enddate2 = enddate1.replace(':','');        
        var enddate3 = enddate2.replace(':','');        
    //    var endate = "*";     
        var date = enddate1.slice(0, 8);        
    var time = enddate3.slice(9, 15);       

        var endateD = date.slice(0, 2);     

        var endateM = date.slice(2, 4);     
        var endateY = date.slice(4, 8);     

    var endateFinal = endateY + endateM + endateD ;


}
```

This function refreshes the site and if the checkbox is checked, this checbox will be unchecked. how can i do to work even if the site refreshes if the checkbox is checked to be checked?

Comment: Call the first function first inside the main one to establish the state of your page then reapply that state after the refresh.

Comment: Use AJAX and don't reload the page at all. Thats faster and creates a better user experience

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone I am new to js, can you explain in more details please?

Comment: I was speaking in the terms of your question as posed however Id say @JonasWilms has the better idea

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone Yes is good idea but the project is big and I am now involved in this project,Thanks

Comment: Are you using PHP in the project, and that's the reason why you need to update the url and reload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a web page is refreshed any state you had in it, in terms of form data like checkboxes, is deleted. You have several options:

1. Use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Save the data in local storage and when the page is loaded read from the local storage and set the checkboxes.
2. Use your server. Send the form data (which checkboxes are checked and so forth) to the server and when the page is loaded make the server send the data to the page. This is not the best solution since your'e saving page state in the server.
3. Use the url. You can save the state of the form in the url using the query string. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970078/modifying-a-query-string-without-reloading-the-page). This means that each checkbox toggle will change the url without reloading.

Comment: Thank you very much, i used the first solution. I am very grateful to you.