# Why history push(query params) reloads the page? React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Problem: When I try to update url by adding query params, page reloads.

.tsx

```
useEffect(() => {
  requestResources()
  requestPosts({})
}, [])

const handleSlideItemClick = (value: string) => {
  history.push(`?resource=${value}`)
}

return (
  Box py={16} px='8px'>
    <SmoothSlider
      list={resources.list}
      name='resource'
      onSelect={handleSlideItemClick}
    />
  </Box>
)
```

Expectation: just update url by adding query params without page reload

I have also tried by `<Link to={`?resource=&{someValue}`}>`, result is same.

Comment: When you say the page reload, do you mean the component remounts? And is your idea only to add new queryparams to url

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes, that's what i want

Comment: Can you create a reproducible demo of your application because it does work as you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pushState to achieve this functionality. It will not reload URL when you update the query URL.

You can implement like this:

```
var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?resource=newValue';

history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
```

Where newurl is your updated URL.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970078/modifying-a-query-string-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `<Link />` and set the property `to` as a [function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-function).

```
<Link to={location => ({ ...location, search: `?resource=${value}` })} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet. After the button press, the 'value' is maintained in React state and passed correctly to URL and React code is not reloaded.

```
import  React, {useState}  from 'react';

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927235/why-history-pushquery-params-reloads-the-page-react
export default function App(props) {


    const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

    function handleSlideItemClick(target) {
        setValue( value + 1);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
        history.pushState ({ }, 'Page Title', `?resource=${value}`)
    }
    // I am using  button for simplicity 
    return <button type="button" onClick={handleSlideItemClick}>Click Me!</button>

}
```