# How to set url when opening a modal

Tags: jquery, url, modal-dialog

I would like to pass a variable into the url when the modal is opened. To achieve that i'm using jquery to set url and then open the modal.

Now my problem is that the modal is getting closed even if i try to open it with jquery .modal('show')

```
value = 5;
window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/gorr/send.php?o=histlist&sid=value;
$('#sendCertificatesModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: What's your purpose? Adding a query parameter to the URL results in a page refresh.

Comment: Be sure you're not asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). If you tell us what you're _actually_ trying to do you may get better help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying a query string without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970078/modifying-a-query-string-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970078/modifying-a-query-string-without-reloading-the-page