# Make Pretty links for this kind of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

Hi guys how you recommend me to do this url in pretty links??
Im trying with htaccess but i don't find a good solution...

```
domain.com/?seite=page1&?id=33&name=1-Free-Cocktails!

for example:

www.domain.com/page1/1-Free-Cocktails!/
```

I have this code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule    ^page1/([0-9]+)/?$   /?seite=page=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule    ^page1/  /?seite=page[NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

**OUTPUT**

```
www.domain.com/page1/
```

**THE BUTTON**

```
    <div class="pull-right kaufen">
<a  href="/?seite=page1&amp;id=<?php echo $item['id'];?>&amp;name=<?php echo $product->prettyLinks($name);?>" class="btn btn-success">Info Anzeigen!</a></div>
```

I will appreaciate your help!!

Comment: A basic rewrite tutorial will cover this. Most of the first page of google for "url rewriting" does just that.

Comment: @JohnConde I read a lot but i don't know how i can do it, you can show me please? i'll appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Your pretty URI doesn't have `id=33` but internal URI does have it!

Comment: yes i only want the name of the product, no the id, is more pretty, i think

Comment: So `domain.com/?seite=page1&name=1-Free-Cocktails!` will also work (without id)?

Comment: no, i make the query by the id, is there a way to hide the id and only show the name of the product? in a pretty link?

Comment: No, URL rewriting isn't a magic, whatever is in URL can be rewritten (hint: look at the URL of this question on SO)

Comment: ??? i dont understand, sorry :(

Comment: If id isn't there in pretty URL then it cannot be used i actual URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want `domain.com/page1/33/1-Free-Cocktails!/` be transformed into `http://domain.com/index.php?seite=page1&?id=33&name=1-Free-Cocktails!`

Put `.htaccess` file to `domain.com/.htaccess`

The contents of `.htaccess` file should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z\0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Z\a-z\0-9\-\_]+)/$ /index.php?seite=$1&?id=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

If You do not need `33/`. That is
`http://domain.com/page1/1-Free-Cocktails!/` transforms to `http://domain.com/index.php?seite=page1&name=1-Free-Cocktails!`, then `.htaccess` would be as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z\0-9]+)/([A-Z\a-z\0-9\-\_]+)/$ /index.php?seite=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

**Update:**
BTW, if You do not want `33/` to appear in the URL You can send it using `POST` as opposed to using `GET`.

To use `method post` You have to use forms. This example has a mix of POST and GET methods. `seite` and `name` are sent using the GET method, while `id` is sent using the `POST` method. It looks a little bit awkward, but here it is:

```
<div class="pull-right kaufen">
<form action="index.php?seite=page1&name=<?php echo $product->prettyLinks($name);?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['id'];?>" name="id" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Then on the PHP page that receives the data, Your `id`, etc. can be output as follows:

```
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["id"]);
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["seite"]);
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);
?>
```

Reference:

[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) (see "Figure 1" in "Regex Back-Reference Availability" section)

[$_POST](http://php.net/reserved.variables.post)

**Update 2**:
You won't be able to implement that in `.htaccess`, because as I stated in one of my comments "You won't be able to rewrite the URL after the page has been loaded". `.htaccess` is not PHP. Your URL would be as follows http://domain.com/page1/1-Free-Cocktails!/. But You can, for example, map Your "33" id to some predefined name and display it in the `<title><?php echo $_POST["id"];?></title>` tag.

However, one of the other options that You have is to use JavaScript and AJAX. But that would be another question. You can start Your research here:

[Javascript: How do I change the URL in the address bar without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7869223/2510628)

[Is there a way to change the browser's address bar without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/352343/2510628)

Comment: Its, works, but you know how i can make like wordpress permanlinks? you know, wordpress have the option to display like this www.domain.com/?p=test or www.domain.com/?page_id=1
and show www.domain.com/test
how i can do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Wordpress, but do You mean that you do not need the "index.php" part in URL rewrite? Some PHP page still has to process Your request.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, i dont want to GET the product by the name, because if you change the name of the product is broken the link, is much better by the ID, and then show the name, in pretty link, is possible to do that?

Comment: You can send "33" using method POST, then it won't appear in the URL. Then it will be in the `$_POST` variable (on the PHP part). You won't be able to rewrite the URL after the page has been loaded.

Comment: i update my question with the code of the button, how i'll make the query via post, i can't understand?

Comment: EXCELENTS! works perfect with the form, but how i can implement in the htaccess? I just copy this in my htaccess??RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z\0-9]+)/([A-Z\a-z\0-9\-\_]+)/$ /index.php?seite=$1&name=$2 [L]

Comment: Answer updated with some choices that are possible. In short, it is possible to use combination of PHP, .htaccess, JS, AJAX, but that would be tricky.