# Detect url change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a url like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/messages/xxx
```

And this url is dynamically changing to

```
https://www.facebook.com/messages/yyy
```

But page is not reloading.
How to detect this changes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change

Comment: It uses `History.pushState `. As explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560617/how-to-change-url-in-browser-without-navigating-away-from-page)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Comment: Chrome extension? [chrome.webNavigator](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) . Especially **onHistoryStateUpdated** event