# Create a false url - Javascript - JQuery - html -

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a One-page website with 3 main pages: as so :

```
<ol class="bar-links">
    <li><a href="#" class="links hvr-grow" data-use="catalogue">catalogue</a>   
    <a href="#" class="links hvr-grow" id="sup1" data-use="news">news</a>
    <a href="#" class="links hvr-grow" id="sup1" data-use="sell">sell</a>
   </li>
</ol>
```

I used `history.pushState()` to change url when someone click on the links, but how can i make the page load when someone enter mywebsite.com/catalogue (or one of the others) because now it says page don't exist (I suppose i need to formulate some kind of GET request ?).

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can use `history.pushState` if your browser supports it.

Refer to [How to change URL in browser without navigating away from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560617/how-to-change-url-in-browser-without-navigating-away-from-page)

Comment: It's working but when I enter "www.mywebsite.com/catalogue" (or the 2 others) in the browser it says web page don't exist.