# How to Update queryParams in URL without reload page in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

I have Angular6 project. It has listing component and detail component. In listing component, I have a search box. When I search anything and based on that when redirecting to the detail page, I am assigning queryParams and when coming back I am preserving those queryParams. And it is working fine.

But again when I type anything in the search box, I want to update the URL with the updated search string that I have entered in the search box without reloading the page again, i.e... I want to keep the queryParams updated while changing the search-box input field.

> listing.component.html

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search">
</div>
<div class="row" *ngFor="let List of Lists | searchFilter:search:'name' | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 25, currentPage: page }">
    <div (click)="editList(List.ListId)">{{List.name}}</div>  
</div>
```

> listing.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.search = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['search'] || '';
}

editPrice(ListId: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['lists/edit', ListId], { queryParams:
        { search: this.search }
    });
}
```

> detail.component.html

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/lists']" queryParamsHandling="preserve">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: You want to update the Url without a page reload or relocate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560617/how-to-change-url-in-browser-without-navigating-away-from-page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `activateRoute.snapshot`, subscribe to `activatedRoute.params`

For Example:

```
 this.activateRoute.params.subscribe((data) => {
     this.search = data.search
     // Your search logic here
 });
```

Comment: In this you again need to call your function search which has the logic of searching @ErVipinSharma

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to update parameter `id` with `anotherId`:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,

) { }


ngOnInit() {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
            this.id = param.get('id');
        });
  }


updateUrl(){

   let anotherId : number = '10'

   let cururl = this.location.path().replace(this.id, anotherId );

   this.location.go(cururl);
}
```

Comment: In my case, I have search variable bound with HTML search box... Then how should I replace search variable => this.location.path().replace(this.id, anotherId );