# Is there a way in nightwatch to click an element but not navigate to the new page?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Is there a way in nightwatch where if I click on a link, it shouldn't redirect me to the url of the link but instead stay on the current page and just update the browser url?

So if I have a link like:

`<a href='/hello' />`

And I click on the link above it should just change the url to `/hello` and stay on the current page.

I didn't find this feature in the docs anywhere.

Comment: That would work in a single page app with client-side routing. Is that what you are testing?

Comment: Yes I have a server side rendered react application with react-router for my client side routing.

Comment: So what is happening when you test it? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: When I click on the link, the browser shouldn't navigate to the `/hello` page but instead should stay on the current page. I forgot to mention that the link within my single page application goes to another application. I ONLY want the url to update with the new link so I can test that the link destination is correctwithout the browser redirecting to the new page.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560766/3044358

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed. But I am not sure how I can get access to the history object in the nightwatch code.