# Change URL with JS or Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, url

I use AJAX in my gallery and I need to change URL in address bar. Is it possible and how? Thanks for replies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

Comment: @RobW Depending on whether or not Filip wants to load the page, and/or whether or not the URL is just a hash change.

Comment: @Phrogz AJAX + "changing URL in the adress bar" ringes a bell at me: The OP wants to change the URL without unloading the page.

Comment: @RobW I suspect you're correct, but I'll wait to hit "Close" until we find out :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the URL and possibly go to a new location (if the URL is not just a "#foo" hash):

```
location.href = 'new url';
```

If you want to 'lie' to the user and have the location change without actually going to the page:

```
history.pushState({}, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

For more on this latter example, read: [Manipulating the Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the the part of the url after the # value, called the location.hash. (Otherwise you'll be navigated to the new url, which you don't want I suppose).

you can set the hash part with an anchor (href="#abc") or with programmatically setting document.location.hash.