# How can I remove the query string from the url after the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, url, query-string

I have a URL with a long query string attached to it.
After the page loads, I do not require the query string. So I want to remove the query string from the address bar without a page reload.

I tried `parent.location.hash = '';` and `window.location.href = '/#'`

They did not make a difference.

Comment: hash is the one that comes after the `#`. query string is the one after the `?` but before the `#`. what you are doing makes no sense. why would you want to hide it?

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript

Comment: please test my code if it works now or not :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove URL parameters without refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753052/remove-url-parameters-without-refreshing-page)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do that without reloading the page, imagine if you could put whatever you wanted in the browser address bar? Security fun :)

**Although** you can now do it in HTML5 (which will only work on browsers supporting it) using the new [history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), but realistically, your scenario best warrants a rewrite instead of including that (seems sledgehammer to crack a nut).

As you said you don't need the query string after the page loads, you should *really* post back, then redirected to another URL after you've finished your processing.

Comment: That isn't true. The [history API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10700997/19068) makes it possible. It has some limits, the main one being that you can't change the URL to one that appears on a different origin, but the question doesn't require that it switch origins.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, I can't delete it (it's accepted) so I've edited to incorporate that. I +1ed yours also :)

Answer (score 52):

As others have said, you can do this using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) in modern browsers (IE10+, FF4+, Chrome5+). There was no full example in the answers, so figured I'd share my solution, as I just had a requirement to do the same thing:

```
history.pushState(null, "", location.href.split("?")[0]);
```

If you are using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), you can also check if the History API is available like so:

```
if (Modernizr.history) {
    history.pushState(null, "", location.href.split("?")[0]);
}
```

Comment: Finally. Someone who just answers the question instead of guessing and assuming things that OP wants and/or needs. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 20):

That is achievable in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) using [the history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), but probably isn't the best solution to your problem.

```
history.replaceState({}, 'some title', '/');
```

It sounds like you would be better off processing the data and then redirecting to the homepage instead of returning an HTML document directly.

Since you aren't wanting to keep the URL around, it won't be useful for bookmarking, so it is quite likely you would be better off making a POST request.

This suggests that you should be using the [POST-Redirect-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: I cannot use a POST because it is the analytics data that is getting passed in the query string

Comment: I don't see how that follows. Even if it does, you can still redirect.

Answer (score 9):

```js
window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 3):

Use `history.replaceState({}, "Title", "page.html");`

same syntax for `pushState`. However you will have to find a way to make IE understand that.

A better way would be to use Apache `mod_rewrite` module. It's quite easy to use.

Comment: But mod_rewrite will redirect to the trimmed url before page loads

Answer (score 2):

I use this code snippit in my personal projects where i need to remove URL params without re-loading:

```
var newURL = location.href.split("?")[0];
window.history.pushState('object', document.title, newURL);
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to add one more way to do this, especially for the ones who are using `$routeProvider`.

As it has been mentioned in some other answers, you do this by using:

```
var yourCurrentUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0]; 
window.history.replaceState({}, '', yourCurrentUrl );
```

or by creating a new record in history stack:

```
window.history.pushState({}, '', yourCurrentUrl );
```

For a very detailed and nice explanation about doing with `history.pushState` and `history.replaceState` , you can read [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753103/2166856) .

**HOWEVER if you are using Angular** `$routeProvider` in your app, then it will still capture this change if that matches with any existing pattern. To avoid that, make sure your `$routeProvider` has [reloadOnSearch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) flag set to `false` because by default it is `true` .

For example:

```
$routeProvider.when("/path/to/my/route",{
   controller: 'MyController',
   templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',
   //Secret Sauce
   reloadOnSearch: false//Make sure this is explicitly set to false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Code Now it will work**

Just Add Below code in you page whose link you want to change.

```
// javascript function

   function buildLin(first) {
    var firs = first.toString()
       //alert(firs);
       //document.getElementById("team").value = "1";
           document.location.hash = "#" + firs.replace(/ /g, "_");
        //alert(document.location.hash);
    }

 //jQuery to call above function after page loads

  $(document).ready(function () {
      buildLin(2);
  });
```

Don't forget to add     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
    on your page
​

Comment: Thank you for the code. But it adds a #2 at the end of the url(after the query string). I wanted to remove the query string from the url after the page loads.

Answer (score -2):

You could avoid a query string altogether by using `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: I cannot use a POST because it is the analytics data that is getting passed in the query string