# Removing the content of the URL bar in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

I got tired of the default **about:newtab** *Firefox* page so I did one myself with all the links I use to visit and a nice design.

The *Firefox*'s **about:newtab** leaves the url bar empty after loading so I was wondering if there was some way to replicate this effect.

I thought maybe a *Greasemonkey* script was the solution, but perhaps it is easier than I think.

Thank You

Comment: Okay! but what is your question?

Comment: Well. Is it possible? What's the easiest way? How to do it?

Sorry if I was not specific enough.

Comment: So you want to clear the URL bar using some shortcut keys?

Comment: I want the URL bar auto-cleared when a specific page is loaded.

Comment: Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700937/how-can-i-remove-the-query-string-from-the-url-after-the-page-loads)