# How to remove certain words in a URL as page loads via JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, esri-maps

I am working with Esri Map. When I tried to load json data on the map, I discovered that Word **findAddressCandidates** is appended to the url when view from the console. So instead having **http://localhost/data.json** and am having **http://localhost/data.json/findAddressCandidates**

How do I remove **findAddressCandidates** from the URL so that I can have **http://localhost/data.json**?

Some Stack Overflow engineers suggests the use of **History API** as per [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700937/how-can-i-remove-the-query-string-from-the-url-after-the-page-loads/28077712).

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript Tutorials: Find places</title>
  <style>
  html, body, #viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.20/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.20/"></script>

  <script>

  require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/tasks/Locator",
    "esri/Graphic"
    ], function(esriConfig,Map, MapView, Locator, Graphic) {


    esriConfig.apiKey = "my api key";

    const map = new Map({
      basemap: "arcgis-navigation"
    });

    const view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
      center: [18.9553, 69.6492], //Longitude, latitude
      zoom: 13
    });


    const places = ["Choose a place type...", "Parks and Outdoors", "Coffee shop", "Gas station", "Food", "Hotel"];

    const select = document.createElement("select","");
      select.setAttribute("class", "esri-widget esri-select");
      select.setAttribute("style", "width: 175px; font-family: 'Avenir Next W00'; font-size: 1em");

    places.forEach(function(p){
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = p;
      option.innerHTML = p;
      select.appendChild(option);
    });

    view.ui.add(select, "top-right");


   const locator = new Locator({
        url: "http://localhost/data.json"
    });


   // Find places and add them to the map
   function findPlaces(pt) {
    locator.addressToLocations({
      location: pt,
      maxLocations: 25,
      outFields: ["Place_addr", "PlaceName"]
    })

    .then(function(results) {
      view.popup.close();
      view.graphics.removeAll();

      results.forEach(function(result){
        view.graphics.add(
          new Graphic({
            attributes: result.attributes,  // Data attributes returned
            geometry: result.location, // Point returned
            symbol: {
             type: "simple-marker",
             color: "#000000",
             size: "12px",
             outline: {
               color: "#ffffff",
               width: "2px"
             }
            },

            popupTemplate: {
              title: "{PlaceName}", // Data attribute names
              content: "{Place_addr}"
            }
         }));
      });

    });

  }

  // Search for places in center of map
  view.watch("stationary", function(val) {
    if (val) {
       findPlaces(select.value, view.center);
    }
    });
  // Listen for category changes and find places
  select.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    findPlaces(event.target.value, view.center);
  });


});
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this ```url.parse(yoururl).pathname.split("/");```.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.