# Using javascript to change url and modify history?

Tags: javascript, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

Example of what I'm trying to do:

User is at `/things/list`, then clicks 'new thing' which takes them to `/things/new` they fill in the needed info for the thing click save and the url changes to `/things/123` and then they  click the back button in their browser and it takes them to `/things/list` instead of `/things/new`. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code that goes from `/things/new` to `/things/123` uses `window.location.replace('/things/123')`, then the back button will go to `things/list` like you want because `/things/new` in the browser history will have been replaced in the history list.