# URL change without page reload in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to avoid page load but the URL should change and should be same in all browser. I am trying to use Ajax post with URL change. I have searched and found it is possible using # or .pushstates().

Link : [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

I tried by using .pushstates() but it doesn't work in IE < 10. I don't want to use # in the URL. Is there any way to achieve this in IE?

Comment: As far as I know, no. pushStates is the way to go, or changing the hash

Comment: Why do you object to using a hash? Is it causing some other issue?

Comment: Not causing issues. Isn't there a way except # for IE < 10 browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the answer is just a plain no, there is no way to achieve this in IE.

You will have to accept using the hash if you want to identify different resources your application with the URL without reloading the page.

***Note***: the semantic of the hash is precisely to identify different resources within the same page, so if you don't reload the page, using the hash might actually be a good thing.