# How to create URLs with html5/dynamic site

Tags: php, jquery, html, web-applications, dynamic

I am in the middle of creating a completely jQuery HTML5 site. The content is all populated by an xml feed. It is all programmatic. Since there aren't any static pages (there's just an index.php), how does one go about indexing content for search engines? What do developers usually do when the site is just dynamically created? What if I want (for instance) to put a "tweet this" button on each page. How could I get that button to create a URL that would then (perhaps) trigger a function that shows the correct content?

EDITED QUESTION

I am asking this - since, with a dynamic site such as the one I am building, there is only one URL - index.php. Now normally a search engine will crawl through the 'pages' of a website. But this doesn't have any pages - it's only dynamic content. There is really nothing for the search engine to crawl. Next, if I click on a link in the site (again the link is dynamically created and links to something else dynamically created) Say for instance I click on "widget 1" and it takes me to that product's description page. I have no way of sending that description page URL because it doesn't have one. So how would you address this issue? In a php situation (also dynamic) you would put the query string in the url. But this is all Jquery - everything is imported into the index.php. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please provide more information and code samples because from this information only, it's not possible to give you a proper answer

Comment: If you're asking how to get your draft/mockup/concept hosted by a web host, google "Web Host". Then buy a domain. This isn't a very well thought-out or well explained question. No one here can understand what you're wanting. Maybe instead of asking in jargon, try more natural terms?

Comment: I have edited my original question. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: `window.history.replaceState('object or string', 'Title', '/another-new-url');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do to make unique URLs (without refreshing the page) is use

```
window.location.hash = '#whatever';"
```

this will give you a URL that if the user shares then you will be able to parse and process to display the right product

however... from an SEO perspective this might not give exactly the result you want because the  hash in the location will be ignored when Google/Bing indexes the page so you may also want to support the use of a querystring parameter (?product=whatever) though that will cause a page reload.

See [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript) for more detail and other suggested solutions