# Understanding why plain redirect is used

Tags: redirect, dns

Recently I took class on [Startup Engineering](https://class.coursera.org/startup-001).

While working on a topic of DNS system I found out that sites tend to use redirects to point their different domain names to the main one.

For example, Google use redirect to `www.google.com` when `google.com` is accessed:

```
> curl -I google.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
...
```

From what I know, redirects slow things down, as to get info where to redirect to, it takes the signal to go double the distance to the web-server, so that increasing overall latency.

I have been told that browsers cache the info of redirects, so that the next `google.com` query will be redirected at once by the browser. But the first one still has to get response about redirect by the server.

It seems to me we can achieve the same thing at DNS level. I know we can't have CNAME record for `google.com` leading to `www.google.com` (as it would turn all email `user@google.com` into `user@www.google.com`). But we can use redirect at DNS level. Or [`DNS ALIAS`](http://blog.dnsimple.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-alias-that-works/). 
As the last step we can change url in the address bar of the browser from `google.com` to `www.google.com` with use of JavaScript.
As to me, this will lead to the same result as using redirect, but will avoid us of having redirect and so that we will serve the resultant page faster.

Still, there should be a reason why plain redirect is used.

So, what is this reason? What is the advantage of using redirect? What are the caveats of redirecting at DNS level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that JavaScript [can't change address in the browser address bar beyond same origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136496/862380).

So the only way to change `google.com` to `www.google.com` is to redirect.

All the redirects and ALIASes at DNS level happen on the side of user DNS server, which returns final IP address of web-server to the user. The hostname sent by browser via HTTP to the server is at much higher level of OSI model. And still web-server receives the original hostname, the only way to change it in the browser address bar is to redirect to the new url.

Answer (score 1):

Redirects are used as RFC 1912 does not permit the use of CNAME records on the apex of a DNS zone. Several DNS providers have built things like "DNS ALIAS" to use server-side redirects on their DNS edge machines to resolve the queries, the 301/302 redirect is simply a way of shunting HTTP traffic to another FQDN. Latency stemming from the use of a 301/302 redirect may vary from one DNS provider to another.