# Replace Values from Url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, pushstate

Here i have a URL in Browser Address bar i want to replace path of Address bar using jQuery.
Some try from my side is as below
Consider url as below

`http://localhost/catID/10/itemID/20`

when i run

```
history.pushState("CatID", "Title", "21")
```

it change location bar as

`http://localhost/catID/10/itemID/21`

but i want result as

`http://localhost/catID/21`

how can i do this using jQuery

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to another page, or you are just trying to obfuscate the URL? Because if you are trying the second, it won't work.

Comment: You can use split function for splitting the string then get what index you need and redirect it through window.location hope you get what you need.

Comment: i want only to change url of location bar from `http://localhost/catID/10/itemID/20` to `http://localhost/catID/21` not to page load of link `http://localhost/catID/21`

Comment: check this thread...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Query not needed. Plain js will do. Just add this code in your function and replace the string with the required arguments. Try it in the console, for an immediate effect ;D

```
window.location = "http://localhost/catID/10"
```

If you do not want to reload the page or use # for changing the url, then use `window.onpopstate` 
[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) on mozilla site.

Comment: this reload page i want only to change only location bar text without reloading page