# Hide url of chrome extension page when new tab is created

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a new tab in google chrome with my extension:

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('page.html')}, function(page) {

   // other code

});
```

But when new page is created the URL looks bad for me, like

```
chrome-extension://dfdnfdnfjdnkdfndfdf/page.html
```

How to create new tab with empty URL ?

I saw other extensions doing similar

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a New Tab [Override Page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html).

Alternatively, you could try manipulating the `window.location.hash` directly from your `content` script, using methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136506/949328).

Comment: Not exactly same. I want to create a new tab when extension browser action icon is clicked.

Comment: I added an update, but in general changing the url so that it doesn't reflect the actual content source can cause problems/confusion.