# Modal URL Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a Bootstrap Modal while changing the URL displayed in the browser's navigation bar. The user is not actually going to a different page, however when the Modal is open the URL will be different. Facebook does this with their URLS when you open photos, pinterest when you open pins, instagram, etc. What's the trick?

Thanks!
(basic skills here)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to take a look at HTML5 pushState(). Check out this article.http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! BTW, does this require adding any additional script libraries? Or is that all the code I need? Many thanks.

Comment: @James : It's proper etiquette to up vote and mark the answer as the correct answer if sp0rkyd0rky answered your question ;) That being said, I'm now looking for the exact same thing as you and hoping the pushState method will help me as well.

Comment: Haha, you are right. I was just starting to user stackoverflow back then. Thats for the reminder @teewuane