# Pushing new state for same URL in Iron-Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, application-state

Can I use Iron-Router in Meteor to push a new state onto the browser's history, without going to a new URL?

I would like to show a modal but enable to user to hide it again using the back button.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this, but I think something based on

```js
Router.go(Router.current().request.url + '/modal')`
```

might work. You define your route with an optional parameter, and if it's `'modal'` then display the modal. That may lead to problems if you have URL parameters, in which case you'd have to get more clever with the URL.

Comment: Thanks, but the premise is to not change the URL. Pushing state to history without reflecting it in the address bar is a valid and useful UX pattern.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't push browser state "silently" with the Iron Router package.  However you can use [one of these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript) or the [HTML 5 History API package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/HTML5-History-API) that wraps this package - https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API