# Loading A Web Page Seamlessly

Tags: javascript

I have seen some websites that include nice transitions between pages, such as sliding or fading, etc. Most of these I have seen are actually one page that just transitions various sections. Then I came across a website that does it differently.

If you view [this site](http://fueled.com/services/) and click the various pages the pages transition smoothly but the URLs are different and it doesn't appear to be one page site with hidden sections.

How is this done? I looked for explanations on how to do this but never found a good answer. Any help in determining how this is done would be great.

Note: I am looking to replicate this feature for websites I build so I am looking for an answer that will explain the idea or process of how this is coded.

Comment: Hi I think this belongs on superuser as it's not a programming question.

Comment: @suspectus - How do you get that? I am asking how this is done. IE: The javascript code or an explanation so I can try to replicate the effect. I edited my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The technique you're talking about is using `history.pushState()` which is quite new feature of html5. More info you can find on [MDN - Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method)

Comment: Very cool! I will have to look into this. Thank You for the answer.

Comment: For more information about that and how this works in browsers which doesn't support pushState() see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/136506/2236166)

Comment: For the same reason I recommend as well: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)

Comment: I was about to post the same link. If you don't mind dropping support for IE 9 and below I don't see why this can't be used now. =>

Comment: In that case it should be completely fine for you to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The trick this page does to move from page A --> page B involves 3 main steps:

1. Load the whole page B or only the content that is different from
   page A (probably using XMLHttpRequest).
2. Swap in the changed content (e.g. updating the body,..)
3. Update the browser location bar with the URL of page B without
   refreshing the page, using a particular HTML5 history method called
   *pushState*.