# MVC Ajax.BeginForm - Update URL in Browser after successful Get Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Ajax form, something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxSerchResult", "Search", new { area = string.Empty }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "Results", LoadingElementId = "Loading" }, new { id = "Search" })
{
//Fields go here
}
```

The question is: how to update the browser url with params i send using AJAX?

Comment: please, take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript)

Comment: but how to make it work with mvc ajax control? im not an expert in javascript...

Comment: take a look on my answer below, anyway you have to use javascript, as only by using javascript you can change url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to use `Ajax.BeginForm()`, you would use "OnSuccess" attribute and [benalman's plugin](http://benalman.com), as without javascript you will not able to change url

[demo of url changing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test1) (jQuery 1.9 required)

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm(
      "AjaxSerchResult",
      "Search",
       new { area = string.Empty },
       new AjaxOptions(){
                         HttpMethod = "Get",
                         UpdateTargetId = "Results",
                         LoadingElementId = "Loading",
                         OnSuccess = "changeUrl(data)"
                        },
       new { id = "Search" }))
       {
          //Fields go here
       }
```

and javascript:

```
    <script>
    function changeUrl(data) {
        //if you are using benalman's plugin with jQuery 1.9
        location.hash = "#my_hash";
    }
    </script>
```

**Note:** but due to using `$.browser` (that was already removed from jQuery 1.9) in the benalman's plugin, i would recommend to use `window.location.hash = "#my_url";` or `window.location.replace("#my_url");` instead of `location.hash = "#my_url";`