# URL Hash Fragment: how to add text in real time

Tags: javascript, uri

I have a table that can be filtered with an input field.  As letters are entered in the field, the content of the table is filtered.  A click on a button is not necessary to invoke the filtering.

The table can also be filtered by several criteria (based on content in the table's columns). My goal is to have all filters in a url hash so that the table can be accessed in its filtered state by sharing the page location.

I would like to extend this URL hash fragment technique to include the search field. At any point as the user is adding letters to the search field they should be able to copy the page location and share or save it.

Is it possible to add the search text to the url hash letter by letter, in real time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript

Comment: I don't think so.  I am looking for real-time updating of the hash, i.e. as you enter text in the table's search field, the characters are added one at a time to the hash simultaneously.  That way if the user copies the URL at any time they will capture all the necessary values to recreate the filtered state of the table by pasting the URL into a new browser window.